# MySQL query error from dump

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to export a mysql table from my local system and importing it over on the server hosted on 123-reg. The information of my local server is:

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.35 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

and the server version is:

Server: --
Server version: 5.5.57-38.9-log
Protocol version: 10
User: --
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

They are both running PHP 7 and I am using the Perch framework. The following is the error I am getting when trying to import.

> INSERT INTO `perch2_content_items` (`itemRowID`, `itemID`, `regionID`, `pageID`, `itemRev`, `itemOrder`, `itemJSON`, `itemSearch`, `itemUpdated`, `itemUpdatedBy`) VALUES (3125, 215, 82, 37, 13, 1000, '{\"_id\":\"215\",\"description\":{\"_flang\":\"plain\",\"raw\":\"Kenco ingredients and quality in an In-Cup drink. Pre filled to ensure the correction dilutions for a perfect drink. Using incup dispensing means no mess, easy vending, suitable for busy waiting rooms, offices and areas with limited kitchen space.\",\"processed\":\"Kenco ingredients and quality in an In-Cup drink. Pre filled to ensure the correction dilutions for a perfect drink. Using incup dispensing means no mess, easy vending, suitable for busy waiting rooms, offices and areas with limited kitchen space.\"},\"image\":{\"assetID\":\"390\",\"title\":\"Columbian In Cup Image new 280x240\",\"_default\":\"\/manage\/resources\/columbianin-cupimage-new-280x240.jpeg\",\"bucket\":\"default\",\"path\":\"columbianin-cupimage-ne[...]

---

> MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\"_id\":\"231\",\"description\":{\"_flang\":\"plain\",\"raw\":\"Kenco ingredie' at line 23

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @IvanBarayev this is how phpmyadmin exported it

Comment: thats escaping the quotes. make sure you use the same settings for import

Comment: @nogad yeah I have done that :/ Gah this is hard to figure out!

Comment: You have not shown the part that caused the error. You showed your INSERT with part of the JSON for `"_id": "215"` but the error message suggests the problem doesn't occur until `"_id": "231"` which must come later in the INSERT statement. Look for mismatched single-quote characters. There should not be any syntax error caused by content inside a string, so it must have terminated the string with an errant single-quote.

Comment: Did you try this mysql_real_escape_string($jsondata); ?

Comment: What came immediately before `''{\"_id\":\"231\",...`?  What version of `mysqldump` were you using?  What version of MySQL was the data in?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.